# How to embed a jquery ui widget into a polymer-dart webcomponent

Tags: jquery, dart, dart-polymer, dart-js-interop

I try to embed a jquery ui widget, f.e. a datepicker into a polymer-dart webcomponent.

The Webcomponent is defined like that:

```
<polymer-element name="my-datepicker">
    <template>
        <div id="datepicker"></div>
    </template>
    <script type="application/dart" src="clickcounter.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

The initialisation of this widget is done in JS like that

```
<script>
    $(function() 
    { $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();});
</script>
```

How can I initialize that widget in dart in my polymer.dart webcomponent.

I tried with 'dart:js' to call that method, but I cannot access the shadow dom with dart:js.

With

```
shadowRoot.querySelector("#datepicker")
```

I can access the shadow-dom, but how can I call a JS method - datepicker() - on that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass an element to *jQuery* instead of a selector. So the following code should work :

```dart
final element = $['datepicker'];
js.context.callMethod(r'$', [element]).callMethod('datepicker');
```

Comment: final element = $['#datepicker']; did not did not initialisize the datepicker, With final element = shadowRoot.querySelector("#datepicker"); it works! Thanks!

Comment: Ooops, I left the prepending `#` . fixed.

Comment: is $['datepicker'] just a "shortform" of shadowRoot.querySelector("#datepicker") or is there a difference?

Comment: Yes, it's the same. See [Polymer.$](https://api.dartlang.org/docs/channels/stable/latest/polymer/Polymer.html#$)

Comment: The solution works fine with jquery datepicker.    With another jquery-widget  [handsometable](http://handsontable.com/) it doesn´t (no error, but no initialisation of the component). Any idea what could be the reason or where I could research.

Comment: good idea ;-) done! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21352628/how-to-embed-the-handsontable-widget-into-a-polymer-dart-webcomponent

Answer (score 1):

Just call JQuery on the element and then call datepicker().
The dart js package makes it human-readable:

```dart
import 'package:js/js.dart';

var element = shadowRoot.querySelector("#datepicker");
var $ = context.global[r'$'];
$(element).datepicker();
```